# iAd with Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iad, watchkit

I have an app that uses iAd on the iPhone. I'm using WatchKit to create the Apple Watch version, and would like my ads to appear there as well. I do not see any options for ads in Interface Builder, yet the interface controller files allow me to import the iAd framework and implement the code. Does WatchKit allow the use of iAd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No ads in Apple Watch right now, so WatchKit does not allow that.